# Data from current date to 30 days after current days

Tags: mysql

Why this query is not working

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE DATE(date) < CURDATE() + 30
```

I am trying to get the data from 30 days but my query is not working.Why

Answer (score 2):

What does `+30` mean? Days? Years? Months? Hours? You need to use (the proper syntax) a format MySQL understands:

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE DATE(date) < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: We should have us a new startup co. - Code Detectives Inc. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not using the right construct, try:

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: this should be DATE_ADD()  
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Fixed, thanks, @AakashMartand; in the future feel free to "edit" the answer yourself

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from today on to 30 days after current day, you've got to set an upper and an lower limit, so use:

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE 
    date >= CURDATE()
AND
    date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 31 DAY
```

Please note that by not using a function on your `date` column you won't prohibit MySQL to use an index on this column.

The lower limit should be obvious, the upper limit means that you've got the complete day that's 30 days later than today. If you use `+ INTERVAL 30 DAY` instead this last day is excluded from the result.